Asymptotic Proof when f(n) & g(n) are known natural numbers
Lets suppose,
f(n) = 125 
g(n) = 25

can we say that f(n) is θ(g(n))? assuming c=1 for worst case and c=6 for best case

If you have two constant functions then they are obviously equivalent up to a constant factor, i. e., $cg(n) \le f(n) \le cg(n)$ therefore $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ by definition of $\Theta$.

And, moreover, they are both $\Theta(1)$.
